# Specifying the font size for the axes labels in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

A couple of years ago, I made a plot using this code:

```
h = 1;
H = (1/2)*(p^2 + x^2);
rho[n_] = (1/Pi)*(-1)^n*Exp[-2*H/h]*LaguerreL[n, 4 H/h];

ImageCrop[Plot3D[rho[0], {x, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200,  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800,  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, FontSize -> 40], Style[p, FontSize -> 40]}, AxesStyle -> 15, Boxed -> False, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20]]]
```

that looked like
[image]

I copied and pasted the code with absolutely no changes into Mathematica 10.1.0.0, and I got this image:
[image]

How do I make the bottom image look like the top image? The one item that I really care about is the axis label. If I label only a single axis, I can use the same code (without the Style[p, FontSize -> 40]), and the axis label is large enough. However, the moment that I add in a label for both the $x$ and $p$ axis, I can no longer make the axis labels larger. Is there an extra graphics option that I need to include?

Comment: Thank you. I am not too sure what I was thinking when I gave AxesStyle a number. I probably had more associated with AxisStyle, but decided not to use it, and forgot to remove the entire directive

Comment: @JasonB `AxesStyle -> 15` is a valid specification for a font size of 15.  Try `AxesStyle -> 50` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason not to use the option `AxesStyle -> 40`. `AxesStyle` affects the axes labels and in a style specification an integer is taken as a point size specification. But if you give the point size specification in `AxesStyle`, you don't need to repeat it in `AxesLabel`.

So you can use simple form.

```
Block[{x, p},
  rho[n_][x_, p_] =
    With[{h = 1, H = (1/2)*(p^2 + x^2)}, 
      (1/Pi) (-1)^n Exp[-2 H/h] LaguerreL[n, 4 H/h]]];

ImageCrop[
  Plot3D[rho[0][x, p], {x, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5},
    PlotPoints -> 100, 
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> 800,
    AxesLabel -> {x, p, None},
    AxesStyle -> 40,
    Boxed -> False,
    TicksStyle -> 20,
    PlotTheme -> "Classic"]]
```

[image: plot]

This image was made in V11.0.1.

P.S. The reason you had ran into a problem with your options was that you specified

```
AxesLabel -> {Style[x, FontSize -> 40], Style[p, FontSize -> 40]}
```

where

```
AxesLabel -> {Style[x, FontSize -> 40], Style[p, FontSize -> 40], None}
```

is required. In a 3D plot you should specify labels for all three axes. If you could get away with specifying labels for only two of the axes in older versions of Mathematica, that was a bug that has been fixed. The form with all three elements specified works as you would expect.